# How can I loop through a list of IP addresses and SSH to each?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I am new to python. I have a list (text file) of Raspberry Pi devices with default credentials. I would like to connect to each, log in and change the password. I am able to do this to individual devices using the following code:

```
import os
import socket
from ssh2.session import Session

host = '172.16.1.119'
user = 'pi'
passw = 'raspberry'

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect ((host, 22))

session = Session()
session.handshake(sock)
session.userauth_password(user, passw)

channel = session.open_session()
channel.shell()
channel.write("echo raspberry | sudo -S su && echo 'pi:newpwhere' | sudo chpasswd\n")
channel.write("exit\n")

size, data = channel.read()

while size > 0:
        print(data.decode())
        size, data = channel.read()

print ("Exit status: {0}".format(channel.get_exit_status()))
```

When I try to use similar code to read a file with multiple IP addresses and perform the same action, I receive an error:

```
import os
import socket
from ssh2.session import Session

user = 'pi'
passw = 'raspberry'
file =  input("please select the file that contains the hosts: ")

with open(file) as f:
    hosts = f.readlines()

def chgpw():
    channel = session.open_session()
    channel.shell()
    channel.write("echo raspberry | sudo -S su && echo 'pi:newpwhere' | sudo chpasswd\n")
    channel.write("exit\n")

for i in hosts:
    print(i)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((i,22))
    session = Session()
    session.handshake(sock)
    session.userauth_password(user, passw)
    chgpw()

print ("Exit status: {0}".format(channel.get_exit_status()))
```

The error that I receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack-ov.py", line 21, in <module>
    sock.connect((i,22))
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

The print statement print(i) does print out the first IP address in the list right before the error occurs at line 21.

Comment: What is the IP that causes the error?

Comment: @Carcigenicate any IP address or even an FQDN. I have also tried using a single IP in the file as well as replacing the file input portions with a static variable definition of a single host and get the same error.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, DNS name resolution works on both the pi as well as the machine on which I am running the code. Also, I am able to get the code to work without the for loop (the first code block in my post).

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried that as well hosts.rstrip() and hosts = f.readlines().rstrip(). I get AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip' but when I add a print statement to print out hosts, I do not see \n

Comment: See my answer. You don't `rstrip` the list, you `rstrip` each host. And `print` makes newlines characters harder to see. `print(list(i))` will show them though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate that is the ticket. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readlines` includes the newline character in each line that it returns. You'll want to `rstrip` `i` before using it.

```
for i in hosts:
    stripped = i.rstrip()
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect((stripped, 22))
```

The newline character was invalidating each address.